# Cambiar datos de una gráfica según la fecha seleccionada

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ajax

tengo unas gráficas que utilizan chartjs las cuales se actualizan según el departamento que el usuario seleccione; ahora, necesito que además del departamento, esta pueda cambiar según la fecha que se seleccione, pero no sé cómo lograr esto.

[image: Gráficas]

Estoy utilizando ajax para que al cambiar los datos del departamento, las gráficas se actualicen; ¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcione ese select junto con la fecha?

El ajax de una de mis gráficas es el siguiente:

```
let dept = $('.js-departamento');
    dept.change(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('get_products_by_department') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                departamento: event.target.value,
            },
            // Agrega el tipo de dato que deseas recibir
            dataType: 'json',
            // Solo necesitas un parámetro
            success: function(data) {
                // Debes recibir un JSON
                console.log(data);

                // Limpiar etiquetas
                artChart.data.labels = [];
                // Limpiar datos
                artChart.data.datasets[0].data = [];
                // Recorrer para actualizar
                data.forEach(row => {
                    artChart.data.labels.push(row.label);
                    artChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(row.data);
                });

                // Actualiza la gráfica
                artChart.update();
            }
        });
    });
```

Y esta es la función que obtiene los datos:

```
public function get_products_by_department(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {

        $dep = $request->departamento;

        if ($dep == !null) {
            //CONTAMOS LOS ARTÍCULOS MÁS PEDIDOS POR DEPARTAMENTO
                $articulos = Articulo::whereHas('detalleventas', function($q) use($dep){
                    $q->whereHas('venta', function($k) use($dep){
                        $k->whereHas('cliente', function($o) use($dep){
                            $o->where('departamento', $dep);
                        });
                    });
                }
                )->with(['detalleventas' => function($q) use($dep){
                    $q->whereHas('venta', function($k) use($dep){
                        $k->whereHas('cliente', function($o) use($dep){
                            $o->where('departamento', $dep);
                        });
                    });
                }])->get();
        } else {
            $articulos = Articulo::with('detalleventas')->get();
        }
        

        $artdep = [];
        foreach ($articulos as $articulo) {
            $artdep[] = ['label' => $articulo->nombre, 'data' => count($articulo->detalleventas)];
        };


        //LO ORDENAMOS Y SELECCIONAMOS LOS PRIMEROS 6 DATOS
        $artdep = array_reverse(array_sort($artdep, 'data'));
        $artdep = array_slice($artdep, 0, 6);  

        if ($artdep == null) {
            $artdep[] = ['label' => 'no hay registros', 'data' => 1];
        }
         
        return response()->json($artdep);
    }
}
```

Acá esta la sección de los select

```
<div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">
                            <i class="fas fa-check-double"></i>
                            Seleccione un departamento
                        </h4>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select name="departamento" class="form-control js-departamento" id="departamento" name="departamento">
                                {{--Construimos las opciones con blade--}}
                                <option value="">Todos los departamentos</option>
                                @foreach($arrayDepartamento as $departamentoitem)
                                    <option value="{{ $departamentoitem }}">{{ $departamentoitem }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
                                <span>Fecha inicial</span>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control flatpickr desde" type="date"
                                        placeholder="click para elegir">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
                                <span>Fecha final</span>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control flatpickr hasta" type="date"
                                        placeholder="click para elegir">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude resolver. Mi función para obtener los datos quedó:

```
public function get_products_by_department(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {

        $dep = $request->departamento;
        $desde = $request->desde;
        $hasta = $request->hasta;


        if ($hasta == null) {
            $hasta = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now())->format('Y-m-d')   . ' 23:59:59';
        } else {
            $hasta = Carbon::parse($request->hasta)->format('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59';
        }

        if ($desde == null) {
            $desde = ('2022-01-01 00:00:00');
        } else {
            $desde = Carbon::parse($request->desde)->format('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59';
        }



        if ($dep == !null) {
            //CONTAMOS LOS ARTÍCULOS MÁS PEDIDOS POR DEPARTAMENTO
                $articulos = Articulo::whereHas('detalleventas', function($q) use($dep, $desde, $hasta){
                    $q->whereHas('venta', function($k) use($dep, $desde, $hasta){
                        $k->whereHas('cliente', function($o) use($dep){
                             $o->where('departamento', $dep);
                        });
                    })->whereBetween('created_at', [$desde, $hasta]);
                }
                )->with(['detalleventas' => function($q) use($dep, $desde, $hasta){
                    $q->whereHas('venta', function($k) use($dep){
                        $k->whereHas('cliente', function($o) use($dep){
                             $o->where('departamento', $dep);
                        });
                    })->whereBetween('created_at', [$desde, $hasta]);
                }])->get();
        } else {
            $articulos = Articulo::whereHas('detalleventas', function($q) use($desde, $hasta){
                $q->whereHas('venta')->whereBetween('created_at', [$desde, $hasta]);
            })->with(['detalleventas' => function($q) use($desde, $hasta){
                $q->whereHas('venta')->whereBetween('created_at', [$desde, $hasta]);
            }])->get();
        }


        $artdep = [];
        foreach ($articulos as $articulo) {
            $artdep[] = ['label' => $articulo->nombre, 'data' => count($articulo->detalleventas)];
        };


        //LO ORDENAMOS Y SELECCIONAMOS LOS PRIMEROS 6 DATOS
        $artdep = array_reverse(array_sort($artdep, 'data'));
        $artdep = array_slice($artdep, 0, 6);  

        if ($artdep == null) {
            $artdep[] = ['label' => 'no hay registros', 'data' => 1];
        }
         
        return response()->json($artdep);
    }
}
```

Y mi ajax:

```
<script>

    
    $('.js-departamento').on("change", function(){
        graficas();
    });

    $('.desde').on("change", function(){
        graficas();
    });

    $('.hasta').on("change", function(){
        graficas();
    });

    function graficas() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('get_products_by_department') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                departamento: $('.js-departamento').val(),
                desde: $('.desde').val(),
                hasta: $('.hasta').val(),

            },
            // Agrega el tipo de dato que deseas recibir
            dataType: 'json',
            // Solo necesitas un parámetro
            success: function(data) {
                // Debes recibir un JSON
                console.log(data);

                // Limpiar etiquetas
                artChart.data.labels = [];
                // Limpiar datos
                artChart.data.datasets[0].data = [];
                // Recorrer para actualizar
                data.forEach(row => {
                    artChart.data.labels.push(row.label);
                    artChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(row.data);
                });

                // Actualiza la gráfica
                artChart.update();
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('get_categories_by_department') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                departamento: $('.js-departamento').val(),
                desde: $('.desde').val(),
                hasta: $('.hasta').val(),
            },
            // Agrega el tipo de dato que deseas recibir
            dataType: 'json',
            // Solo necesitas un parámetro
            success: function(data) {
                // Debes recibir un JSON
                console.log(data);

                // Limpiar etiquetas
                catChart.data.labels = [];
                // Limpiar datos
                catChart.data.datasets[0].data = [];
                // Recorrer para actualizar
                data.forEach(row => {
                    catChart.data.labels.push(row.label);
                    catChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(row.data);
                });

                // Actualiza la gráfica
                catChart.update();
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```